# How do you copy whole project/app to another name?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

How do you copy whole project/app to another name?
Sometimes I'd like to make some code changes, but I'd rather try it out on a copied version of my code.  I was thinking in terms of coping the whole app to another name.

Is this possible?
Or... just thinking now, does XCode provide sometype of versioning in its software.  Meaning, create a new version (from 1.0 to 1.1), make changes to v1.1.  If I don't like, can revert back to v1.0.  Simplistic wording...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

version is possible

but if you want to copy.... in finder, copy project folder and copy it to some where else.
then open from that location...change version number

Comment: So there is some sort of versioning in XCode?  I'll have to research more on that then.  And just copy the folder in Finder rather than in XCode, got it.  I was wondering if there was a way in XCode also.  Thanks!

Comment: I see what versioning does... and seems more for when you upload apps to the Apple and have versions of your app.  But I do see that you can take a snapshot of the app, then create a new version.  You can then restore from the snapshot if necessary.  For what I want to do, much simpler to use Finder.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are desperate for a source control system. Xcode integrates with git, so I would look at that. In this case you would create (using git) a branch to experiment on 1.1 in; and you can easily switch between branches (1.0, 1.1, ...). You may like to browse http://git-scm.com/book

Using something like git means you wouldn't need to use Finder to create an experimental version of your project. It also means you can easily move code between your test branches and the master branch that you use to ship releases.